# Get the current and next value in a Jinja for loop

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

Is there a way to iterate over a list in Jinja2 that can access the nth and (n+1) th element in a single iteration?

```
{% for x in my_list %}

<!-- print the current and the (current+1) -->
{{x}}, {{x+1}} <-- this is wrong but hopefully highlights the problem

{% endfor %}
```

Also, does the for loop allow for a "step" increment?

Comment: You should be able to write a loop `for i in range(len(my_list))`, just like a normal python loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jinja has a [`loop.index`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#for) variable that you can use to access the next value in your list:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template_string("""
        <body>
            {% for x in my_list %}
                <p>
                    {{ x }} {{ my_list[loop.index] }}<br>
                </p>
            {% endfor %}
        </body>
    """, my_list=range(10))
```

> 0 1
>
> 1 2
>
> 2 3
>
> 3 4
>
> 4 5
>
> 5 6
>
> 6 7
>
> 7 8
>
> 8 9
>
> 9

Answer (score 2):

As of [Jinja v2.10](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/changelog/#version-2-10), we can use `loop.nextitem` instead of the `my_list[loop.index]` trick. Similarly `loop.previtem` is also available. :-)

From the above hyperlinked changelog:

> Added `previtem` and `nextitem` to loop contexts, providing access to the previous/next item in the loop. If such an item does not exist, the value is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an example with loop.nextitem would help.

The value I'm monitoring is in the first column of my list of rows.

Try something like this:

```
{% for row in mylist %}
    {% if row.rowtype == "Selection" %}
        {% if loop.changed(row.rowid) %}
            <br/>{{ row.rowprompt }}:
            <select name="{{ row.rowname }}" id="{{ row.rowname }}">
            <option value="{{ row.rowvalue }}">{{ row.rowvalue }}</option>
             {% set isSelectStart = 1 %}
        {% else %}
                <option value="{{ row.rowvalue }}">{{ row.rowvalue }}</option>
        {% endif %}
        {% if loop.nextitem is defined and row.rowid != loop.nextitem[0] %}
                    </select>
        {% endif %}
        {% if loop.nextitem is not defined %}
                    </select>
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```